# SQL Server Browser Service on AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is the SQL Server Browser Service supported on RDS? If so, how do I enable it?

Our app needs the SQL Server [Browser Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087(v=sql.105).aspx) running on UDP port 1434. The [usual instructions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) do not apply since this is a managed SQL Server instance on AWS RDS. The AWS RDS docs do not seem to mention the Browser Service and I've looked at RDS Option and Parameter groups but nothing obvious stands out that would enable that.

Update: I should also mention that I've also added a security group that allows TCP 1433 and UDP 1434 from the app server. TCP port 1433 is reachable.

Comment: Relevant thread. It doesn't make it fully clear how to enable the service, but has clues. Perhaps you could work it out based on that thread then post an answer to make it clear to others. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=767301

Comment: That thread seems to be for a self-managed SQL Server running in a regular EC2 instance.

Comment: If no-one else can help you, pay the $29 for a month of AWS developer support. If you must have this service, and RDS doesn't support it, you can of course run it on EC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting AWS support it turns out this is not possible:

> This service is disabled on RDS instances to reduce resource usage and also exposure of instance information that can be obtained from it (security).
>
> As RDS does not support multiple SQL Server instances running on the same machine (named instances), and only the database engine is available there is no need for having the SQL Server Browser running on it.

Comment: I think that was money well spent, to find that out. Now you can either accept this or install SQL Server on EC2. SQL Server is in the AWS Marketplace, which could make installation easier. Here's an example link, note it might not be the best and the link will eventually stop working: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results?x=0&y=0&searchTerms=microsoft+sql+enterprise+server+2016&page=1&ref_=nav_search_box